# Haskell equivalent to class specialization in OOP

Tags: oop, haskell, inheritance

I'm testing some optimization techniques for rendering static voxel scenes and learning some Haskell along the way. I have voxels defined as

```
type Voxel = ( VoxelId, Position ).
```

where `VoxelId` is simply an alias for `Int`. Since I anticipate some linear algebra down the line, I wanted `Position` to represent 3-dimensional vector. Library I'm using ([matrix](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/matrix-0.3.5.0/docs/Data-Matrix.html)) implements only `Matrix` data type, but having Position have underlying type of `Matrix` only simplify further computations, so I'm okay with that.

However, it doesn't make much sense for `Position` to be anything else than 3-dimensional vector, so I'd like to constrain `Position` to 3x1 matrices, so when I use specifically `Position` in a function signature, I'm guaranteed to expect either 3x1 matrix or compilation error.

In C++ or other OO language I could do something like this:

```
class Matrix
{
  Matrix(int rows, int columns)
  {}
}

class Position : public Matrix
{
  Position()
  : Matrix (3, 1)
  {}
}
```

and use `Position` when I expect only 3x1 matrix and reference to Matrix everywhere else.

Let's assume `Matrix` from the library I'm using have a constructor function

```
matrix :: (rows) -> (columns) -> Matrix
```

How can I replicate this behavior in Haskell without redefining for `Position` all operations `Matrix` implements?

Comment: It makes little sense to construct an immutable but empty vector in Haskell. What you can do is define your own "smart constructor" (a basic function) which only accepts e.g. `(Double, Double, Double)` and returns the matrix. If you want to have more static guarantees, put the resulting matrix in a `newtype` wrapper (note that this will require to define all the matrix operations on the wrapper as well, or unwrap every time).

Comment: Redefining matrix operations for Position defeats the purpose of using third-party library and it's something I was leaving as a last resort solution. I edited original question to make it more clear.

Comment: Then you have to manually unwrap every time, or use safe coercions. Or use a dumber constructor as I show below.

Comment: Your OO example with subtypes doesn't actually give you the type safety you're looking for. Sure `Position` automatically creates a 3 x 1 matrix, but all the actual functionality inherited from `Matrix` doesn't know that, and will happily let you try things that only make sense for other dimensions. So there's no point looking for a way to replicate that. What you need is a **parameterised** type where the dimensions are represented in the type: `Matrix rows columns`. Then you just define a type synonym `type Position = Matrix 3 1`.

Comment: Doing that needs a fair few extensions though (to get type level numbers of some kind), and moderately advanced techniques (much of which can be implemented in libraries with a fairly friendly interface, but probably not wrapped around your existing matrix library without some specific wrapper reimplementations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Haskell there's no subtyping like in OOP.

You can define you own data type

```
newtype Position = P { unP :: Matrix ... }
   deriving (Show) -- , etc.
```

and a smart constructor

```
position :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Position
position x1 x2 x3 = 
   Position (newMatrix 1 3 [[x1,x2,x3]])  -- pseudo code
```

If you really want to hide the internal representation, you can put the above in its own module and export only the smart constructor. Doing that however will require you to define and export all the operations you need on this `Position` type, otherwise it will be too opaque to be useful.

Assuming you don't hide the representation, note that `Position` and `Matrix ...` are two distinct types. So you can't pass a `Position` to something which wants a `Matrix`. So, instead of

```
matrixMultiply somePosition someMatrix
```

one needs to do

```
matrixMultiply (unP somePosition) someMatrix
```

and get a `Matrix` result. If the result should be a `Position` instead, one can/needs to define a custom multiplication function:

```
posMultiply :: Position -> Matrix ... -> Position
posMultiply m _ | wrongSize m = error "matrix has the wrong size!"
posMultiply m (Position p) = Position (matrixMultiply m p)
```

Depending on how much static guarantees you want, this may get a bit cumbersome.
In many cases, [safe coercions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html) can soften the pain.

A simpler alternative could be to have a dumber constructor which does not use a custom type. This is a plain function

```
position :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Matrix ...
position x1 x2 x3 = 
   newMatrix 1 3 [[x1,x2,x3]]  -- pseudo code
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I have some idea how to handle this problem now, although I have to admit I'm not a huge fan of any of those solutions (they are definitely better than anything I came up with tho).

I remember a talk by Simon Peyton about trade-offs of type system in Haskell, where he said something along the lines of: "in Haskell it's easy to add new functionality to existing type, while in imperative languages it's easy to give new type existing functionality, but in both cases inverse gets really messy" and I suppose this is the case that shows how true is this statement.

Comment: @ReverentLapwing Yes, I agree. This is known as the ["expression problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem).